# Image Link for Facebook Instant Articles

Tags: html, css, wordpress, facebook, facebook-instant-articles

How do I add a URL link to a image using Facebook instant articles?The link seems to be removed while viewing the preview of the instant article.

Comment: I am not sure if that is directly possible; you might have to go via embeds and embed a document containing the link with the image inside it via iframe.

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution to this problem?